# Is Cronbach's alpha used outside of psychology?

Tags: measurement, statistics

Tau-equivalent reliability ($\rho$<sub>$T$</sub>), also known as [Cronbach's alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha) is a widely used measure of reliability in psychological testing. I've not encountered Cronbach's alpha in other sectors. Does Cronbach's alpha have use-cases outside of psychology?